# how to get imageview nil checked in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

hi
  I have a UIImageView(reimg1),while loading it for the first time i should not have any image so i will make the image nil.

```
if (reimg1.image == nil) {
   NSLog(@">>>>>>>> image view is empty");
} else {

}
```

Comment: Three answers..but what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

check if(image==nil) or set some default image when image is empty

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set image nil first time then set property like this

```
[self.reimg1 setImage:Nil];
```

if u wan tto check means whether it has data in it

```
if(reimg1==nil)  
{  
..  
}
```

or else convert **NSdata** and check its values

Answer (score 0):

See [UIImage.image](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

Checking if an imageView is empty.

```
if ([imageView isEqual:nil]) {

    //if the image view is empty do the following
    NSLog(@"imageView:%@ is empty", imageView);


}else{

    //If the image view is not empty do the following
    NSLog(@"imageView:%@ is not empty", imageView);

    //For example, in viewDidLoad, you could set UIImageView as nil
    [imageView setImage:nil];

}
```